# How does vertx create eventloop thread

Tags: java, netty, vert.x

I tried `DeploymentOptions.setEventLoopPoolSize(even number x)`, but it actually creates x/2 threads, odd number is ok.

The code is simple like this:

```
public final class Bootstrap {

    private static final VertxOptions VERTX_OPTIONS;
    private static final Vertx VERTX;

    private static final DeploymentOptions HTTP_SERVER_DEPLOYMENT_OPTIONS;

    static {
        VERTX_OPTIONS = new VertxOptions();
        VERTX_OPTIONS.setEventLoopPoolSize(22);
        System.out.println("Event Loop Pool Size: " + VERTX_OPTIONS.getEventLoopPoolSize());

        VERTX = Vertx.vertx(VERTX_OPTIONS);

        HTTP_SERVER_DEPLOYMENT_OPTIONS = new DeploymentOptions();
        HTTP_SERVER_DEPLOYMENT_OPTIONS.setInstances(24);
        HTTP_SERVER_DEPLOYMENT_OPTIONS.setWorkerPoolName("http-server-worker");//remove this line you can create the right number of thread
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VERTX.deployVerticle(MyHttpServer.class, HTTP_SERVER_DEPLOYMENT_OPTIONS, ar -> {
            System.out.println("success");
            System.out.println("is Worker? " + HTTP_SERVER_DEPLOYMENT_OPTIONS.isWorker());
        });
    }
}

public class MyHttpServer extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        String content = "I'm " + this + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " router: " + router;

        router.get("/").handler(context -> {
            context.response().end(content);
        });

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(80, ar -> {
            if(ar.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("server start " + this);
                startPromise.complete();
            } else {
                ar.cause().printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

wertx-web 3.9.2

When opening Java VisualVM, you can see the difference between setting and not setting WorkerPoolName.
[Java visualVM image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bplbr.png)
When you set it, and EventLoopPoolSize is a even number, the number of threads actually created is halved.
What's the matter with `setWorkerPoolName()`?

Answer (score 0):

I read source code and find that the method

```
private static EventLoop getEventLoop(VertxInternal vertx) in io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
```

has an interesting behavior：no matter who call this method,it give you an EventLoop object from an array one after another.It actually implement in io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutorChooserFactory.GenericEventExecutorChooser,
an inner class,it has a method next()

```
    @Override
    public EventExecutor next() {
        return executors[Math.abs(idx.getAndIncrement() % executors.length)];
    }
```

So when you create a thread for an EventLoop, and exactly get all the EventLoops that all corresponding to even(or odd) index,half of the EventLoop array will be missed.

And,when vertx deploy verticles,it will see if you setWorkerPoolName:

```
for (Verticle verticle: verticles) {
  WorkerExecutorInternal workerExec = poolName != null ? vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor(poolName, options.getWorkerPoolSize(), options.getMaxWorkerExecuteTime(), options.getMaxWorkerExecuteTimeUnit()) : null;
  WorkerPool pool = workerExec != null ? workerExec.getPool() : null;
  ContextImpl context = (ContextImpl) (options.isWorker() ? vertx.createWorkerContext(options.isMultiThreaded(), deploymentID, pool, conf, tccl) :
    vertx.createEventLoopContext(deploymentID, pool, conf, tccl));
```

If you did,it will create 2 Context for this step.
This means it will call the getEventLoop() method twice to get EventLoop for each Context.
In summary, if you set the poolName, each Verticle will get the EventLoop twice when it is deployed, but only one thread will be created.

I don’t know if this is a bug, because I’ve just been in contact with vertx for two days, and I don’t know if this is a deliberate design.I just want to control my thread number by setEventLoopPoolSize() method.